# Как сделать так чтобы блок расширялся при добавлении содержимого

Tags: css, вёрстка

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Comfortaa300';
    src: url('../../assets/Comfortaa300.ttf');
}
.items {
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 2px;
    background-color: #404040;
}
.item {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #1E1F21;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #DDDCDD;
    align-items: center;
    width: 140px;
    min-height: 70px;
}
.weekend {
    background-color: #282a2b;
}
.currentDay {
    border: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #1E1F21;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
.event {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: unset;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: left;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
.ev_btn {
    font-family: 'Comfortaa300';
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    left: -42px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 114px;
    border: unset;
    background: unset;
    color: #DDDDDD;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    top: -5px;
}
```

item - Сам блок который нужно расширять содержимым.
event, event_btn - это список кнопок и кнопки которые нужно добавлять в блок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй использовать width: fit-content; (для height тоже самое). Не ручаюсь, что сработает, CSS сам себе на уме, так что пробуй все, пока не получится.

Comment: Это нужно в класс с айтемом место height ? Т.е height: fit-content; ? Нужно расширить блок в высоту

Comment: что то не получается, вообще без понятия как это сделать, но хотелось бы чтобы вся строка с блоками расширялась, если в одном слишком много записей

Comment: Да, но как уже сказал - работает не всегда, пробуй разные варианты. Если совсем застрял поищи свой вопрос в ютубе + попробуй забить свой вопрос в гугл или в ютуб на английском, если на русском не находишь. Уверен штука распространённая.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Overflowing_content

Гугл в помощь

Comment: все гуд, я в классе в css, оставил height как было, а в jsx в переменной кинул это значение height: fit-content; , все работает спасибо